# Opening Index.html leads to a blank page

Tags: html, reactjs, web-development-server

I'm new to web development and found a website prototype, but when I tried to open it by clicking on the index.html in the files, it's completely blank. The only thing I see is on the tab, and it just says "React App".

How do I make the website components actually show? I know there should be something showing because I can see all of the code and pages, but nothing shows?? Is there some other way to open the website?

Comment: can you share a link of the project or a screenshot of the folder structure?

Comment: if you open the project in VSCode. open the terminal and then run `npm install` and then `npm start`. it should open a server you can visit in your local browser. something like http://localhost:3000

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

React is a library that compiles all your javascript then renders it in index.html file. If you open the file directly you won't see anything. If you want to run your project then:

1. Open the project folder in vscode.
2. Press `CTRL+J` if you have windows.
3. Type `npm install` - It will install all project dependencies listed
   in `package.json` at the root of your project.
4. Then run `npm start` - This will start development server locally
   that you can use to develop your project as you go.
5. Then go to `App.js` and make changes and see how the server
   automatically refreshes.

to learn more, go to [Get started with react - FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/getting-started-with-react-a-modern-project-based-guide-for-beginners-including-hooks-2/)